# i have this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.gestion</groupId>
<artifactId>bp</artifactId>
<name>banque</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <!-- <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version> --> 
       <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> whene i test
>
> > INFO : org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@996db8: startup date [Mon Aug 29 16:50:37 CEST 2016]; 
> >     root of context hierarchy
> >     INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
> >     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)ext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
> >         at test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:11)

Comment: Please check if you have multiple versions of Spring core jar.

Answer (score 1):

your pom depends on spring-core 4.1.1, this method has been introduced from version 4.2 , your spring-context version and spring-core version are not compatible each other.

Comment: yes, it will solve the problem , first try to run mvn dependency:tree  , then you find out the versions for each jars, then probably you might need to change the spring-core to compatible version , might be 4.2

Comment: ok debug the test, put the break point at line number 11 of TestMain class, and when break point hits, try to evaluate following expression and let us know the output  Class.forName("org.springframework.core.ResolvableType").getResource("ResolvableType.class")

Comment: what is the output you got from maven dependency tree after edited your pom (changing spring core 4.2 )?

Comment: its display nothing but when i execute this line:  IBanqueMetier metier=(IBanqueMetier) context.getBean("metier"); ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 498

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have an older version of Spring being pulled in as a transitive dependency of another library. Spring 4 introduced a Bill of Materials feature to solve just such issues. You can use this:

- by removing the `<version/>` element from **all** Spring libraries declared in your POM.
- by adding the following section to your POM (setting the version as required).

POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

See further:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-rc2-available

> You can import the spring-framework-bom project in your dependency
>   management section to ensure that you get consistent Spring Framework
>   dependencies. **This is particularly useful when you work with other
>   projects that may have transitive dependencies to earlier versions of
>   Spring.**

Answer (score -2):

The java.lang.NoSuchMethodError you're encountering indicates that the Java runtime is trying to access a method that does not exist in the version of the Spring Framework being used. In this case, the method in question is org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal.withInitial(java.lang.String, java.util.function.Supplier).

This error often occurs when there is a version mismatch between the Spring modules in your project.

If you're using a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle, update your Spring dependencies to the latest versions compatible with your project. Be sure to update all relevant Spring modules to avoid version conflicts.

Keep all your dependencies namely (spring-context ,spring-core, spring-framework, spring-web, spring-web-mvc ) to the same version ... do not allow different versions which may lead to such exceptions.

as of dec 2023 version 6.1.0 for all these dependencies work fine